# sLaravel load model related values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables,

```
users(id, username, password);
profiles(id, user_id, first_name, last_name, gender);
```

with respective models as **User** and **Profile**

My existing code,

```
$users = User::all();
return Response::json($users);
```

I want to return the profile values as well along with the users as json format without preprocessing or building an array/object, is there any shortcut method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to use relationship and eager loading.

Once you have defined the relationships correctly you'd do:

```
$users = User::with('profile')->get();
return Response::json($users);
```

You can access a user profile data like that:

```
$user->profile->first_name
```

And that would only mean running two queries - one for users and one for their profiles.

P.S. you missed a "s" in your `return Response::json($userS);`